# Is there a guide to updating a 2.5 extension to 3.x?

Tags: joomla-3.x, migration

I've searched around a bit but didn't find a guide yet. Something with a checklist would be great.

Comment: Do you mean something like the [Adapting a Joomla 1.5 extension to Joomla 2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_2.5) article but for 3.x?

Comment: Yes, I just looked at that article and I would say I'm looking for the equivalent for 2.5 to 3.x.

Comment: I stumbled up this article which looks helpful http://macrotoneconsulting.co.uk/index.php/Company/extension-changes-for-joomla-3-0.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While not an as extensive guide as [Adapting a Joomla 1.5 extension to Joomla 2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aAdapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_2.5) these two backwards compatibility articles on [Joomla Doc's](http://docs.joomla.org/) helped us.

- [Potential backward compatibility issues in Joomla 2.5 and Joomla Platform 11.4](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_2.5_and_Joomla_Platform_11.4)
- [Potential backward compatibility issues in Joomla 3 and Joomla_Platform 12.](http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2)2

**Update**

Nick also found this non-Joomla Doc's article:

- [Extension Changes for Joomla 3](http://macrotoneconsulting.co.uk/index.php/Company/extension-changes-for-joomla-3-0.html)

Comment: Thanks @cppl. If others find helpful links they will post here. Google indexes stack exchange pretty well so most people also looking for the answer to my question will find this page.

Answer (score 1):

There is a doc page explaining the potential backward compatibility issues between 2.5 and 3.x. http://docs.joomla.org/Potential_backward_compatibility_issues_in_Joomla_3_and_Joomla_Platform_12.2

Make sure you don't use any of the deprecated and removed methods found in there and the extension should work in J3.x.

Comment: Ummm the questions about updating an extension, I sort of read that to mean something like the [Adapting a Joomla 1.5 extension to Joomla 2.5](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Adapting_a_Joomla_1.5_extension_to_Joomla_2.5) article…

Comment: Ah sorry, misread the question then.
Changed my answer now.